# Python gc.get_referents() returning references that are unknown to inspect module

Tags: python, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am trying to debug a memory leak and have tracked it down to a single object, call it "parent".

`gc.get_referents(parent)` indicates that it is effectively gaining more and more references to the object that is leaking. I'm trying to find out more information about how it is happening, however, `inspect.getmembers(parent)` knows nothing about these references that gc.get_referents does know about:

i.e.

```
import gc
import inspect

parent = someObject()
dependents = gc.get_referents(parent)
fromInspect = [b for (a,b) in inspect.getmembers(parent) if b in dependents]
notFromInspect = [b for (a,b) in inspect.getmembers(parent) if b not in dependents]
print len(fromInspect)
>>> 3
print len(notFromInspect)
>>> 69
```

So there are lots of objects (69 of them!) that the gc module knows about, but inspect does not.

How does `gc.get_referents()` construct the list of "referent" objects for a Python object?

Do I need to look at slots? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out that "parent" was a custom python object implemented in C/C++.

The documentation here describes how you can write your own "container" objects in Python: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC

All that such objects have to do to then interface with the garbage collector is provide two function pointers, [`tp_traverse`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_traverse) and `tp_clear`.

`tp_traverse` allows a custom type object to tell the Garbage collector anything it wants about which objects this object owns.

So in my case, this is how I am seeing references which are unknown to the `inspect` module.

Unfortunately for me, I still haven't found the actual cause of the leak - except now I know it's related to the C/C++ code.